# GhostScript cropped PDF incorrectly displays on iOS/Android

Tags: pdf, crop, ghostscript

I am using the following command to crop a PDF:

```
gswin32c -dQUIET -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dFirstPage=1
-dLastPage=1 -o output.pdf -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=237 -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=151
-dFIXEDMEDIA -c "<</PageOffset [-64 -396]>> setpagedevice" -f input.pdf
```

My intention is to crop the input.pdf 3.4 inches from top boundary, 0.9 inches
(0.9 x 72 = 64) from left boundary, 5.5 inches (5.5 x 72 = 396) from bottom boundary, 4.3 inches from right boundary, and everything seems to work fine and the output.pdf displays appropriately cropped while viewed on a desktop (Adobe, Chrome Browser etc). However when The same PDF is viewed on iOS or Android device, seems like the
page shift has occurred along the dimensions mentioned and areas from uncropped
regions are still visible. It almost seems like the page size did not work
appropriately.

Reading some online forums, I have also tried the following commands but none
seems to have any cropping effect, even on a desktop viewer:

```
gswin32c -dQUIET -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dFirstPa
ge=1 -dLastPage=1 -o outupt.pdf -c "[/CropBox [64 396 237 151] /PAGES pdfmark"
-f input.pdf


gswin32c -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dFirstPage=1 -dLastPage=1 -o output.pdf -dDEVI
CEWIDTHPOINTS=237 -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=151 -dFIXEDMEDIA -c "237 151 translate 6
4 396 237 151 rectclip" -f input.pdf
```

Any help offered is very much appreciated unless this is a bug!

Many Thanks,
Kaushik

Answer (score 1):

This was opened as a Ghostscript bug report, investigated and answered there, you can find the details at:

http://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=693081